# Typescript interface for an array

Tags: typescript

This seems like a dumb question, but here I am.

I know an interface can be used to define an object and its keys, but how do I make an interface if that object is an array?

For example, the interface for

```
const object = {
   bar: 1
   foo: 2
}
```

would be

```
interface myInterface {
   bar: number
   foo: number
}
```

What if my object is:

```
const object = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,0]]
```

What about a 3D array?

How do I define this interface?

Comment: it depends how precise you want to be, but first let me say that in for example vscode, just hovering over 'object' will tell you it's a number[][], a 3d array would be like number[][][]. As mentioned you can use tuples to be more restrictive about the length of the array, and account for different types in different positions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple):

```
const object: [
  [number, number, number],
  [number, number, number],
  [number, number, number]
] = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,0]];
```

Or using a type additionally:

```
type Point3D = [
  [number, number, number],
  [number, number, number],
  [number, number, number]
];

const object: Point3D = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,0]];
```

**Note:** `Point3D` is restricted to exactly three times `[number, number, number]`.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. I figured the answer was going to be very very simple.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a type for that, for example:

```js
type MyArray = number[][];
```

To hold a 2D array of numbers.

Or you can use the [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type if you want your arrays to have a set length or hold values of different types in different positions:

```js
type MyArray = [number, number, number][];
```